# UIActivityViewController Gmail Share Setting Subject Same as Body

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, gmail, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was trying to implement invitation with the help of UIActivityViewController. I did what needs to be done to set up.

I tried to share the URL with iOS native mail app, subject and body seems to be different strings but then i downloaded gmail from app store. While inviting through gmail app, i found out that both subject and body are going same.

I tried to search on net but everyone is saying that its a gmail bug. Has anyone ever found the solution.

Please do reply, it will be of great help

Comment: Happening with React Native as well.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for this? I want to share just a plain text in the body and subject.